# jQuery .attr() not work on jQuery.dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-dialog

I've HTML tag like this:

```
<div id="user-detail"></div>
```

That's for **jQuery.dialog** container. And the dialog script...

```
$('#user-detail').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 700,
        show: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: 'slide',
            duration: 500
        }
    });
```

When I call a function to show it, I adding `.attr()` to give the tag new attribute `title`.

```
function user_detail(id){
    var output = call_ajax('/customer/ajax_get_detail', 'id=' + id);

    $('#user-detail').attr('title', 'User Detail')
                     .dialog('close')
                     .html(output)
                     .dialog('open');
}
```

and blah.... the `.attr()` not work. What is the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hack it like that:

```
$("span.ui-dialog-title").text('User Detail');
```

Answer (score 0):

If User Detail string is common for all,Do not mess up.

use

```
<div id="user-detail" title="User Details"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/GnpQ8/3/

Make sure your variable `output` has data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#user-detail').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 700,
        show: {
            effect: 'fade',
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: 'slide',
            duration: 500
        }
    });

    $('#user-detail').attr('title', 'User Detail')
                     .dialog('close')
                     .html('HI, I am a dialog.')
                     .dialog('open');
});
```